# How can I set value in a text box presented in a Bootstrap Model using placeholder

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I want to set value for name using **selenium webdriver** in **firefox** (*please see below image*), but this text box is presented in  **Bootstrap Model** and it doesn't have **Id** or **Name** attribute,
it just have **placeholder** and **type** attribute (*please see second image*). I am working on this for last few hours but nothing helpful.

I am trying below code:

```
> WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Name')]"));
```

Below is few line from HTML:

```
<div class="modal welcome__modal  is-active">
<div class="modal__overlay welcome__modal__overlay" style="background-color: rgba(71, 70, 86, 0.1);"></div>
<div class="modal__content welcome__modal__content" style="padding: 10px 0px; width: 600px;">
    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;"><span style="opacity: 0;">_</span>
        <div class="welcome__modal__content__wrap" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="welcome__modal__content__heading"><a class="welcome__modal__content__heading__logo" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 1px;"><img src="/5729a135ccb77ae7a0744b6903af9cb8.svg" alt=""><img src="/6e963a3bd5d0e46cfc51abd29cb5e047.svg" alt="" style="margin: 3px 0px 0px 10px;"><h1 class="sr--only">Primedice</h1></a>
                <h3><span>The most <strong>popular</strong> and <strong>trusted</strong> Bitcoin gambling website.</span></h3>
            </div>
            <form class="welcome__modal__content__form" autocomplete="off"><input placeholder="Name" type="text"><button class="btn"><span><!-- react-text: 971 -->Join <!-- /react-text --><strong>3,241,212</strong><!-- react-text: 973 --> players now<!-- /react-text --></span></button></form>
            <div class="welcome__modal__captcha is--hidden">
                <div>
                    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                        <div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LeX6AcTAAAAAMwAON0oEyRDoTbusREfJa2vxDMh&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9wcmltZWRpY2UuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=en&amp;type=image&amp;v=r20171115120512&amp;theme=light&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=c2gxjjpxcbva" role="presentation" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" height="78" frameborder="0" width="304"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-1" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="welcome__modal__content__login"><span>Already have an account?</span>
                <!-- react-text: 978 -->&nbsp;
                <!-- /react-text --><strong style="cursor: pointer;"><span>Login here</span></strong>
                <!-- react-text: 981 -->.
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="welcome__modal__content__terms"><small><span>By accessing the site I attest that I am at least 18 years old and have read the</span><!-- react-text: 985 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text --><span style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: 600; cursor: pointer;"><span>Terms &amp; Conditions</span></span><!-- react-text: 988 -->.<!-- /react-text --></small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somebody, please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is going? If my answer was helpful -- please check a tick near the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that the text box is presented in Bootstrap Modal Dialog Box so we have to construct a proper `xpath` with proper `wait` as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait_modal = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait_modal.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal__content welcome__modal__content']//input[type='text' and @placeholder='Name']"))).sendKeys("debanjan");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below way:

First get the root element and keep it to a WebElement object. Then find the form element and finally send the value to input element.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal__content.welcome__modal__content"));
//wait until the form is appeared [here apply wait functionality]
WebElement username = elem.findElement(By.className("welcome__modal__content__form"));
username = username.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));
username.clear();
username.sendKeys("John dohn");
```

Comment: @Rik Can you send the full html element with more parents elements

Comment: @AliAzam please see updated question, added html with question.

Comment: @Rik just wait a minute

Comment: @Rik I've updated my answer. Please try to implement this and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find element by its placeholder:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Name']"))
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I am trying below code but it is not setting value for name---- WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Name']"));
              username.clear();
              username.sendKeys("rikhi.sahu.001");